# My Asp.Net Form data is not being submitted properly by Selenium 2 (Webdriver)

Tags: webforms, selenium-webdriver

So I have written a test which populates a form, saves (in the admin tool), and then publishes.

However, my form is being lost between the save click and the publish click. I would show what the form looks like in HTML, but its pretty huge (like 20-30 fields)

In psuedo code, filling out the form looks like this:

1) Fill in form using dropdowns
2) Hit the save button - saves all form data 
3) Hit the publish button

When I pause the script to see what is happening within selenium, I see the form properly being populated. I then see the Save button properly being clicked. When I pause the screen before hitting publish, I see that the content I have saved after clicking the save button was lost or is in the wrong fields.

When I do this manually, it works correctly. I know selenium submits forms differently than the standard user, however, is there anything I can do on my end to make sure that form is being submitted properly?

Answer (score 0):

What does the `Save` button actually do? Is it Javascript, or a simple ` button?

Are you using the C# interface to Selenium webdriver? You probably have code that looks something like this:

```
FillInForm();
selenium.click(By.CssSelector("input[value='Save']"));
selenium.click(By.CssSelector("input[value='Publish']"));
```

Have you tried inserting, between `save` and `publish`, lines like the following:

```
// further up: By saveButton = ...
// By formField = ...

selenium.click(saveButton);
var formField = selenium.FindElement(formField);
Assert.That(formField.GetAttribute("value")
    .contains("The text you typed into the form")
);
```

The point here being to check that `save` really is doing what it says on the tin. Generally, when you ask the WebDriver to "click" on a button, it does do exactly (more or less) what the user does. Alternatively, you can inject some javascript to force the form to submit - but then you're explicitly *not* testing what the user actually does (but you might find it's closer to what you experience).

Comment: Hi Jelford, thanks for the feedback.  let me answer your questions. 1) It is not a standard button, it is actually an "a" tag with href="#Save".   2) I did the above example with checking the value attributes. They are different after clicking save (they are empty of value) So I know that save click isn't emulating exactly what the user would do. I have thought about using javascript to force the correct form submission, but not sure what I need to call. Should I just be going to myUrl.com/#Save?

Comment: My mistake. Its not href=#Save, its an input tag. So probably a normal button? Not sure what the standard button tag would be.

Comment: I also just want to mention that not all of the fields are getting messed up. Of the 20-30 fields in the form, only 2 fields are getting lost between save and publish.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. A normal button submit button looks like `<input type="submit" />`. A standard (non-javascripty) button would be somewhere inside a `<form>` element, which should have an associated `action` attribute (or if not, it defaults to the URI where the page is). Try sending a POST request (using CURL) or something to wherever the form submits (the `action`), and see what happens.

Comment: The other thing to check is the following: If your page *does* rely on Javascript to work properly, then you must be using a WebDriver client that support JS; specifically, the `HTMLUnit` driver (the most basic, quickest one, that ships with Selenium) does *not* support JS. If you're using e.g. Firefox or Chrome drivers, then this also isn't the problem.